# Iterate through part of a list in C++

Tags: c++, iterator

I am new to C++ and I am working on an implementation of merge sort to help familiarize myself with the language.

Currently I have a list of integers and I want to create 2 sublists and store the first half of the original list into a list named 'left' and the remaining half into a list named 'right'

Ex: Assume my original list data is 16, 24, 56, 12, 89; I want to iterate through this list adding
16, 24 to a new sublist 'left'
and adding 56, 12, 89 to sublist 'right'
So left would result in [16, 24]
and right would be [56, 12, 89]

Here is the code I have right now; what conditions should I write in my if statements?
('l' is the name of the list that is passed in the function's parameters)

```
    list<int> left, right;
    int midpt = l.size()/2;
    for(listIt = l.begin(); listIt!= l.end(); listIt++){
       if () left.push_back(*listIt);
       if () right.push_back(*listIt);
    }
```

Comment: Are you just trying to implement the merge part, if not that would be a good way to start

Answer (score 7):

This might be easier:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

auto middle = std::next(l.begin(), l.size() / 2);

std::list<int> left(l.begin(), middle), right(middle, l.end());
```

This constructs two new lists, `left` and `right`, directly from the respective ranges. The `std::next` algorithm returns an iterator obtained by advancing the given iterator by the given number of steps. Note that `std::list<int>::size()` has constant runtime complexity as of C++11, though iterating the iterator takes a linear amount of work.

Comment: I like this answer, because the two lists get their content already in their constructors.

Answer (score 0):

This would work.

```
list<int> left, right;
int midpt = l.size()/2;
int count = 0;
for(listIt = l.begin(); listIt!= l.end(); listIt++){
   if (count++ < midpt)
       left.push_back(*listIt);
   else
       right.push_back(*listIt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::list::insert` instead of a for-loop. Try -

```
left.insert(l.begin(), l.begin() + midpt);
right.insert(l.begin() + midpt, l.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that `std::list` defines a doubly linked list, it might be worth considering a somewhat different approach. Instead of finding the middle of the list, and adding what's left of that to one list, and what's right of it to the other, you might consider adding the first element to your `left` list, the last element to your `right` list, advance both iterators, and repeat (until the iterators meet).

Most of the other methods require a linear traversal of the list to find the middle, followed by linear traversal of both sides to build the two new lists. In other words, you traverse the list 1.5 times.

By traversing from both the front and back simultaneously, you can do the whole job by traversing the list only once. In terms of big-O complexity, these are equivalent (O(N) in both cases), but in more practical terms we can expect traversing the list once to be somewhere around half again faster than traversing it 1.5 times (though depending on the list size, caching will probably affect that to at least some degree).